# How to search multiple columns of the datatable based on this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

DataTable is able to create.Now i can only able to search the column named 'No'. My requirement is to search any number of desired colums of the datatable.Is there any problem by doing like this? can anyone help?

```
dmhTable = $('#tableId').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "bLenthChange" : false,
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        "sAjaxSource" : "searchHistoryByFromAndToDate.html?fromDate="+ $('#txtFromDate').val() +"&toDate="+ $('#txtToDate').val(),
        "oLanguage" : {
        "sSearch" : "Search"
                      },
        "aoColumns" : [{"sTitle" : "Sl No","mData" : null,"aTargets": [ 0 ],
        "fnRender" : function(obj) { var columnIndex = obj.oSettings._iDisplayStart + obj.iDataRow+1
                                                   return columnIndex;
                                   }
                       },
                       {"sTitle" : "ID","mData" : "ID", "bSearchable" : false,"bVisible":false},
                       {"sTitle" : " No","mData" : "No", "bSearchable" : true},
                       {"sTitle" : " Type","mData" : "Type", "bSearchable": true},
                       {"sTitle" : "Message","mData" : "Message", "bSearchable": true}
                      ],
        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                        "dataType" : 'json',
                        "type" : "GET",
                        "url" : sSource,
                        "data" : aoData,
                        "success" : fnCallback
                      });
                   },
                        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
                      });
```

Comment: Is the searching handled by the server-side code?

Comment: Can we see it please?

Comment: @markpsmith sorry.. searching is not handled by the server-side code

Comment: You have `bServerSide` set to `true` which means that searching is done by the server side. Besides `bLenthChange` that has to be renamed to `bLengthChange` I don't see anything wrong with the initialization code.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I did  the change that you have mentioned(bLengthChange). But still its not working.

Comment: The important part of @Gyrocode.com's comment is this: **You have bServerSide set to true which means that searching is done by the server side**, so when you say 'searching is not handled by the server-side code', you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: So, did you change to `"bServerSide" : false` and you still have the issue?